# Add a right border to a label

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to do add a right border to my label. In CSS, you can to this with a few lines of code:

```
label {
        border-right : 2px solid #000;
      }
```

This seems to be different in Xamarin.Forms XAML as there are no border properties on any of the elements. This is similar to what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: please click the image]

Here is my code:

```
<ListView x:Name="listview" SeparatorVisibility="None" 
          HasUnevenRows="True" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="20, 10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding LoremIpsum}"
                           HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding LoremIpsum1}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding LoremIpsum2}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Is there any way I can add a right border to the label? I tried using a BoxView with `WidthRequest = 1` and `HeightRequest = 10` but it did not work. I even tried using an image but that is not good practice. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can I wrap the label in a border? With a box view? @Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Grid Layout and BoxView to show the right border with color green and width 2

eg.

```
 <ListView x:Name="listview" SeparatorVisibility="None" 
          HasUnevenRows="True" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid  Margin="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <BoxView  Grid.Column="0" Color="Green"/>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Padding="20, 10">
                        <Label  Text="{Binding LoremIpsum}"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding LoremIpsum1}" />

                        <Label  Text="{Binding LoremIpsum2}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>                    
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this will not work, can't add grid inside viewcell. The app will break immediately. Any other idea? :)

Comment: @IdevDev - no reason you can't use a Grid inside a ViewCell. The `</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` in the code above was just placed in the wrong spot. Should be fixed now.

Comment: It was my mistake. Thanks @HiteshPatil

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate solution to using a Grid, you could also accomplish this with a StackLayout. The key here being to nest your original StackLayout inside another, with `Orientation="Horizontal"`.

```
<ListView
    x:Name="listview"
    SeparatorVisibility="None"
    HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackLayout
                        Padding="20, 10"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding LoremIpsum}"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding LoremIpsum1}" />
                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding LoremIpsum2}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <BoxView
                        WidthRequest="1"
                        Color="Green" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help I used the grid solution :)